# Allow arbitrary data-* attributes on React component with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is there a way to allow dynamic `data-*` attributes on the below React component with Typescript? I would like the ability to:

1. Support `className`, `style`, and other common HTML attributes
2. Allow `data-*` attributes
3. Allow custom component props like `custom`

```
interface ITestProps {
  custom?: string;
}
export const Test: React.FunctionComponent<
  ITestProps & HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>
> = ({ children, className, custom, ...rest }) => (
  <div className={className} {...rest}>
    {children} {custom}
  </div>
);
```

Usage:

```
<Test data-some-random-text="Hello World">test</Test>
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from TS 4.1 you can do it like this

```
type TestProps = { 
  custom?: string; 
} & {
  [key: `data-${string}`]: unknown;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not like how you're thinking, no. But you can make this work, even if you don't get helpful type hints. Just disable some or all (like I've done) typechecking for your component and just deal with the props directly:

```
export const Test: React.FunctionComponent<any> = (props: any) => {
    let rest: any = {};
    for (let property in props) {
        if (property.indexOf("data-") === 0) {
            rest[property] = props[property];
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className={props.className} {...rest}>
            {props.children} {props.custom}
        </div>
    );
};
```

My two cents is you shouldn't do this and either predefine all your properties or pass a single object with all your data-.